# Prevent fixed sidebar menu to scroll over footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, emotion

Hi is there a simple way to prevent a fixed sidebar som scrolling over a footer or a specific element? I've tried changing it from fixed to absolute depending on different viewport height but my application is nested in a lot of position relative elements so I haven't managed to get it to work yet.

Here is a code example: https://codesandbox.io/s/fixed-sidebar-7gvpf?file=/src/index.js

Ask if I need to clarify anything.

Thanks beforehand,
Erik

Comment: Add `height: 100%;` and remove `position: fixed;` in your `Sidebar`.

Comment: I see the misconception here but I want to see the sidebar when i scroll. I just don't want to overlap when I scroll past the footer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Because the element is `fixed` and therefore outside the normal page flow you can `z-index` to specify if an element is above or below another.

In your case you can use it like this with `z-index: -1;` so it wil be positioned behind the element.

```js
const SideBar = styled("div")`
  background-color: green;
  height: calc(100vh);
  width: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
`;
```

If this causes the sidebar to disappear behind everything you also can set the `z-index` on the footer with `position: relative;` to get it to work. like the following CSS:

```js
const Footer = styled("div")`
  background-color: blue;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
`;
```

Here is an MDN article on z-indexes if you want to know more
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/Adding_z-index